GeoServer GeoWebCache in pending state for indefinite period
I am using GeoServer 2.25.x deployed on EC2 instance.
I have configured tile layer with GeoWebCache to create tiles.
My volume where I was creating tiles was getting out of free space, so I stopped on going seeding and increased the volume size by 150 GB.
After increasing the volume the seeding is in pending state for indefinite period.
Tried created new tile layer, I can see new xml file is created in geoserver/data_dir/gwc_layers however I cannot see new folder being created in geoserver/data_dir/gwc
I have set geoserver logging settings to VERBOSE_LOGGING, I can view seeding events getting started
XX XXX XX:XX:XX TRACE  [gwc.layer] - --> GWC Seeder Thread-16 submitting getMap request for meta grid location [26488, 7304, 14] on org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerMetaTile@xxxxxxxx

However there are no error logs.
I have checked the user for geoserver and it is root. I am able to create file and folder inside geoserver/data_dir/gwc using mkdir and touch so that rules out permission issue.
How do I identify the reason for this indefinite state of pending?


don't run GeoServer/GWC as root its a huge security risk and can cause permission problems later
